# Making speed of MemberQ comparable with explicit If?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, syntax, compile, memberq

Consider the following two lists:

```
listtest = {11, 13, 22, 221, 1, 3} // Sort // N;
pdglisttest = RandomInteger[{-222, 222}, 10^6] // N;
```

For the given element of `pdglisttest`, I want to return 1 if it belongs to `listtest` and 0 otherwise. In the real case, `listtest` and `pdgtest` are not fixed, and this operation is just a sub-action required when calculating some quantity.

I make two codes - one using `MemberQ` and another one without it, by using explicit `If`:

```
comp = Compile[{{list, _Real, 1}, {pdglist, _Real}}, 
  If[MemberQ[list, Abs[pdglist]], 1, 0], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]
comp1 = Compile[{{pdglist, _Real}},
  Module[{pdg},
   pdg = Abs[pdglist];
   If[pdg == 1. || pdg == 3. || pdg == 11. || pdg == 13. || 
     pdg == 22. || pdg == 221., 1, 0]
   ], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]
```

It turns out that the one with `MemberQ` is triple as slow:

```
t=comp[listtest, pdglisttest]; // AbsoluteTiming
t1=comp1[pdglisttest]; // AbsoluteTiming
t==t1
```

> {0.0855261,Null}
>
> {0.0257923,Null}
>
> True

However, `MemberQ` is very convenient and probably unavoidable if `pdglist` is not fixed. Is it possible to speed it up, or the slowdown cannot be handled?

**Edit**

Adding the option `Parallelization->True` to both codes reduces the timing difference down to a factor of 1.5-2, but it is still present.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly adding a levelspec? It might help because it does not try to 'dig deeper'…

Comment: Again: I recommend to sort `listtest` and run a binary search. Should be the same algorithm as in `MemberQ` (but compilable).